# Where these special meta tags applied to?

Tags: html, seo

On the Windows 8 website when I look at the code they have written I found some meta tags which I think are not commonly used.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/cougar-mountain-zoo-download-theme

Is that kind of code used inside the company or applied to everyone's website?

```
<meta name="MS.PageId" content="839880" />
<meta name="MS.PageVer" content="49" />
<meta name="MS.Nav.Level" content="3" />
<meta name="MS.Nav.Channel" content="Download-Shop" />
<meta name="MS.Culture" content="en-US" />
<meta name="Search.os" content="Windows" />
<meta name="Search.Product" content="eADQiWindows 7XVcnh" />
<meta name="Search.Product" content="eADQiWindows 8XVcnh" />
<meta name="Search.Product" content="eADQiWindows RTXVcnh" />
<meta name="Search.SupportedOS" content="eADQiWindows 7XVcnh" />
<meta name="Search.SupportedOS" content="eADQiWindows 8XVcnh" />
<meta name="Search.SupportedOS" content="eADQiWindows RTXVcnh" />
<meta name="Search.AppliesTo" content="WOL" />
<meta name="Search.PageTitle" content="Cougar Mountain Zoo theme" />
<meta name="Description" content="Enjoy the menagerie in this free theme for Windows featuring the inhabitants of Cougar Mountain Zoo." />
<meta name="Search.Culture" content="eADQien-USXVcnh" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/Resources/3.6/WOL/shared/images/Win8_Logo_144x144.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#1A1A1A" />
<meta name="MS.BIAuthStateLoggingDisabled" content="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside **description**, None of those are considered by Google and most look like they are very specific to Microsoft and their own systems. They have "ms"  in their names or gibberish content.

Answer (score 1):

These are primarily for Search Engine Optimization SEO. They does not add anything to the user interface, but are parseable text.

These are also used to specify the author and keyword informations too..

Comment: "These are also used to specify the author and keyword informations too". You are right on what you say. I am corious about another part of this thing which look like microsoft's personal SEO. Check tiggerito's answer make me thing It's right.